# Creating a new column in a data frame based on start dates and end dates

Tags: r

I have the following 2 data frames:

```
Dataframe1 <- data.frame(Time = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-09-06 4:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2017-09-08 15:00:15"), by = "15 min"))
Dataframe2 <- data.frame(Start_Date = as.POSIXct(c("2017-09-07 4:32:00", "2017-09-07 13:02:00", "2017-09-08 10:20:00")), End_Date = as.POSIXct(c("2017-09-07 7:20:00", "2017-09-07 17:46:00", "2017-09-08 13:41:00")))
```

I want to create a new column in `Dataframe1` (`Dataframe1$New_Column`) that is of class `"logical"`. If values in `Dataframe1$Time` are between start dates and end dates (i.e., if they are between the two dates in each row of `Dataframe2`), `Dataframe1$New_Column` will be `TRUE`, and if they aren't, `Dataframe1$New_Column` will be `FALSE`. The result should look like:

```
Dataframe1$New_Column <- TRUE
Dataframe1$New_Column[which(Dataframe1$Time > Dataframe2$Start_Date[1] & Dataframe1$Time< Dataframe2$End_Date[1])] <- F
Dataframe1$New_Column[which(Dataframe1$Time > Dataframe2$Start_Date[2] & Dataframe1$Time< Dataframe2$End_Date[2])] <- F
Dataframe1$New_Column[which(Dataframe1$Time > Dataframe2$Start_Date[3] & Dataframe1$Time< Dataframe2$End_Date[3])] <- F
View(Dataframe1)
```

What is an efficient way to do this using base R functions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-equi join might be better

```
library(data.table)
Dataframe1$New_Column <- TRUE
setDT(Dataframe1)[Dataframe2, New_Column := FALSE, 
            on = .(Time > Start_Date, Time < End_Date)]
which(!Dataframe1$New_Column)
#[1]  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 132 133 134 135 136 
#[17] 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

---

With `base R`, we can use `lapply/sapply` to loop over the rows of 'Dataframe2' and do the comparison

```
out <- !Reduce(`|`, lapply(seq_len(nrow(Dataframe2)), 
       function(i) with(Dataframe1, Time > Dataframe2$Start_Date[i] & 
           Time < Dataframe2$End_Date[i])))
which(!out)
#[1]  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 132 133 134 135 136 
#[17] 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150


Dataframe1$New_Column <- out
```